# Meaning of "off" as "the total number of"

Tags: meaning

I remember that once I saw "off" used (my teacher told me it is British English but I cannot seem to find it in a dictionary) meaning "total of" - so off 10 (or maybe it was 10 off - I do not remember corectly, but it was not about percent or reductions) meant of the total number of 10 items e.g. all 10 cars were serviceable. Could someone shat some light on that? If the above is not enough I shall look for a better example.

Comment: Yes, please include a better example.

Answer (score 3):

This is a usage that is mainly British. The OED  defines it thus: *"Used with a preceding numeral to represent a quantity in production or manufacture, or an item or number of items so produced. Usu. as one off"*

"One-off" is the usage you will be most familiar with, often meaning "one of a kind" or custom made.

It tends to be more common in the trades (plumbing, engineering supplies, etc) and manufacturing and will be seen on invoices, orders etc.

Note also the expression   ***to [number off](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/number-off)***:

> - (adverb) to call out or cause to call out one's number or place in a sequence, esp in a rank of soldiers   ⇒ *the sergeant numbered his men off from the right*.

Answer (score 0):

It can be used to denote ["a quantity produced at one time."](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/off)

> Kienzle printers: *6 off*, surplus to manufacturing requirements.